# Using NSPredicate to get an array of Core Data objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios, nspredicate

Say I have a Core Data entity called Person. How would I get an NSArray of Persons whose properties match certain values? For instance someone of a particular age, height, or weight... or someone with a whose height,weight and age are specific values...

Can I use an NSPredicate like so:

```
NSPredicate *pred = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"(age == 25) OR (height_in_cms == 185) OR (age == 30 AND height_in_cms == 170 AND weight_in_kgs == 80)"; 
// All properties are NSNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the syntax for `predicateWithFormat:`, but you have the basic gist. You can find details on the format in Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html). If you're asking what to do with the predicate once you have it, here is a snippet that shows you the steps:

```
// Create a fetch request.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

// Set the entity for the fetch request.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[entity release];

// Set the predicate for the fetch request.
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Perform the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];
```

If you want the results to be sorted, you can pass an array of sort descriptors to the fetch request using `setSortDescriptors:` prior to executing the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the given statement if you have these value in a variable.

[fetchResults filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age == %i OR hieght== %i AND weight==%i",age,height,weight]];

And also your approach is correct in case for specific values but your statement having syntax error so maintain proper syntax